# App crashes when inserting new row in tableview in swift?

Tags: swift, tableview

I have been trying to insert a new row in tableview but it crashes the app whenever I try to do that.
I have two view controllers. First controller has the tableview and second controller has some textfields. We add some values from textfields in anarray and then show those values in previous tablview. First time the values gets printed on the tableview but the second time it crashes(it should add a new row and show values on that row).

In first controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrObj.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "view") as! ViewCell
       
            cell.label.text = arrObj[indexPath.row].category!
```

In second controller:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "viewcontroller") as! viewcontroller
                   
             vc.arrobj.insert(KeyValues(date: textfeild.text!, category: textfeild.text!, amount: textfeild.text!, tax: textfeild!.text!), at: 0)
             vc.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)// Error:  Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Can anyone tell where I went wrong?

Comment: I didn't create the array struct global which led to the crash.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the table view is not connected (yet) right after the controller has been instantiated.

Delete the line to insert the row

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "viewcontroller") as! viewcontroller           
vc.arrobj.insert(KeyValues(date: textfeild.text!, category: textfeild.text!, amount: textfeild.text!, tax: textfeild!.text!), at: 0)    
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

and in the destination controller in `viewWillAppear` reload the table view

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

There is no benefit to insert the row animated because you won't see it

Comment: Your code works fine but it doesn't insert new row instead show the value on same row of tableview.

Comment: `reloadData()` displays the data source array in the table view. As the controller has just been created there is only one row, unless you populated the data source array somewhere between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` in the controller.

Comment: It am not able to understand. Can you please explain with an example.

Comment: This is an example. `instantiateViewController` creates a new blank controller with an empty data source array `arrobj` – unless the array is populated inside the controller. Before presenting the controller you insert an object, so there is **one** object aka one row.